# Linux header files referenced by mac80211 missing

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, headers

I am using Linux `3.2.0-24-generic`. I need to modify the source files of `ath9k` and `mac80211`. One of the files in `mac80211` refers to a few linux header files such as `linux/slab.h`, `linux/skbuff.h`, `linux/etherdevice.h` and `linux/if_arp.h`. I have installed the latest headers but these are still missing. Where can I download these header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers are part of the same Linux source tree as your modules, in the `include` directory.

(When compiling in-tree modules, you need to have the complete source tree, from a tarball or Git repository. See, for example, [this CentOS article](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules#head-d2e4c05886f94c701e4ae74387d41d8c40c25d01) and the `Documentation/kbuild/` directory.)

```
linux
├── Documentation
│   └── kbuild
├── drivers
│   └── net
│       └── wireless
│           └── ath
│               └── ath9k
├── include
│   └── linux
└── net
    └── mac80211
```